# Django - Log response for each request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

I have an API built using Django framework . I have to log the following datapoints for each time a request hits the API.

1. Request Method
2. Request Path
3. Request object
4. Response Status code
5. Response Latency (if possible)

I tried using the `request_finished` signal but it does not bring the response object with it. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for **Django Middleware**: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/middleware/

When you install "a middleware" you get opportunities to intervene before, during and after request processing, for all requests.

As described in the documentation link, you need to create a Middleware class and then reference it in your `MIDDLEWARE` list in the `settings`.

The class based Middleware is simple enough, but more flexible (easily holds state and has it's own methods). Something like this:

```
class LogRequestsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        response = self.get_response(request)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        self.log(request, start, end)
        return response

    def log(self, request, start, end):
        # log request.method, request.path_info, etc.
        # log end - start for duration
```

There are other hooks in this setup but you shouldn't need them. Even if there's an uncaught exception, Django will process it and still return a response object (from `get_response`) for you to read.

Bear in mind this is not the same request object you get in a view. It's an instance of `django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest`, but those values you are looking for should all be there.

To calculate latency you can take values from `time.perf_counter()` both before and after the request is processed in your `__call__` method, and the difference is the duration:

```
elapsed = time.perf_counter()  # Includes time elapsed during sleep system-wide
duration = time.process_time()  # Process time not including sleep
```